# Is storing instances of a class in a class variable a good pattern

Tags: python, class, oop

One design pattern I use a lot in Python is this:

```
class Foo:
    foos = []
    def __init__(self, argument):
        initialize_instance()
        foos.append(self)
```

Does this have a name, and is it considered a useful pattern?

Comment: This is basically a variant of the [registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html).

Comment: If you use it alot, then obviously it is useful, isn't it?

Comment: @freakish Not necessarily - it could be an antipattern, or there could be a better solution.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Solution to what? We don't know what is the problem you are solving. Plus I don't believe in antipatterns. If it solves your problem then it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think that this is a good practice in OOP (I'm not an expert in Python). The use of a static (like the list `foos`) is almost always a bad conception. Like said in the comments, a better solution is to set a service class (look at the SOA pattern in OOP) to index all your instances of `Foo` and retrieve them further.

However, do not think this is a variant of the registry pattern. This is rather an antipattern of this pattern preventing correct low coupling between classes. Of course, Python is not the better language to do a strong OOP and respect this, but I would'nt recommend to do that anyway.